# is there any implement of CallContext.GetData / SetData in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

`AsyncLocal<>` in .NET Core like `CallContext.LogicGetData`/`LogicSetData`. How about `GetData` and `SetData`?
`Thread.GetData/SetData`, `ThreadStatic`, `ThreadLocal` all of these has same problem, when `Thread` finish, these value will not clean, and if these `Thread` reuse(or maybe `Thread Id` reuse), the *LocalValue* is already exists.

```
class Program
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static string Static;
    private static ThreadLocal<string> Local = new ThreadLocal<string>(false);
    private static LocalDataStoreSlot Slot = Thread.AllocateDataSlot();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threadIds = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (threadIds.Contains(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
                {
                    if(Static == null || Local.Value == null || Thread.GetData(Slot) == null)
                    {
                        // never get in
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // same thread id always already exists value
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    threadIds.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    if (Static == null && Local.Value == null && Thread.GetData(Slot) == null)
                    {
                        var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
                        Static = threadId;
                        Local.Value = threadId;
                        Thread.SetData(Slot, threadId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //never get in
                    }
                }
            }).Wait();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I know how `CallContext` do, it just copy `LogicalCallContext` values to child thread and do not copy `IllogicalCallContext`. But .NET Core only `IAsyncLocalValueMap` in `ExecutionContext`, and it always copy to child thread(except SuppressFlow). So, is there any implement of `GetData`/`SetData`? or any way to clean `ThreadLocal` when its finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a change handler for the AsyncLocal to clear the value when the thread changes?

```
private static AsyncLocal<string> AsyncLocal
    = new AsyncLocal<string>(ThreadContextChanged);

private static void ThreadContextChanged(AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<string> changedArgs)
{
    if (changedArgs.ThreadContextChanged &&
        changedArgs.CurrentValue != null)
    {
        AsyncLocal.Value = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, its useful. I have seen this parameter before, but the name let me feel its only trigger when value changed.